# Why does "Satan in Goray" abruptly change in style at the end?

Tags: isaac-bashevis-singer, yiddish-language, satan-in-goray

When I glanced at the Goodreads page for *Satan in Goray* by Isaac Bashevis Singer (translated by Jacob Sloan), part of [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/158469053?book_show_action=true) caught my eye:

> Unfortunately the ending did fall a bit short. It was forced & rushed, needlessly Singer tried changing his style in order to give the story a more parable/myth like atmosphere which simply didn’t work & destroyed most of his previous build-up.

After reading the book myself, I'm forced to agree. The end of the book makes an abrupt change in style that feels like Singer didn't feel like actually finishing the book and so simply wrote a summary of the end of the story instead of actually writing it out.

Why this sudden change in style?